# Distributed cache stuck on starting

Tags: sharepoint-server, distributedcache

**Issues**

1. In Central admin under Manage Services  the **Distributed cache
   service is stuck on starting**.
2. One of the cache hosts in the cluster is down one server A.
3. More Cache hosts are running in this deployment than are registered with SharePoint for Server A and Server B

**Server Config**

```
8 server SharePoint farm
Server A and Server B:  Distributed cache servers
Server C and Server D:  Front End servers
Server E and Server F:  App servers
Server G and Server H:  OWA servers
```

`Get-cachehost` cmdlet **Service status Up** for both Server A and Server B.

**Steps so far**

- Restarted AppFabric service on Server A and Server B
- Added service account to local admins on Server A and Server B
- `Stop-CacheCluster` and `Start-CacheCluster`
- Restarted Server A and Server B
- `export-cacheconfigserver`

**Configuration Server A**

```
HostName        : ServerA
ClusterPort     : 22234
CachePort       : 22233
ArbitrationPort : 22235
ReplicationPort : 22236
Size            : 5125 MB
ServiceName     : AppFabricCachingService
HighWatermark   : 99%
LowWatermark    : 90%
IsLeadHost      : True
```

**Configuration Server B**

```
HostName        : ServerB
ClusterPort     : 22234
CachePort       : 22233
ArbitrationPort : 22235
ReplicationPort : 22236
Size            : 5125 MB
ServiceName     : AppFabricCachingService
HighWatermark   : 99%
LowWatermark    : 90%
IsLeadHost      : True
```

Comment: Have you tried to restart using Powershell:
Stop-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance – Graceful

  It may help to install latest app fabric CUs/Updates and try again

Comment: Have you installed the AppFabric CU3 or later? CU7 is the latest CU. There were issues with Distributed Cache functioning as expected with the version of AppFabric that is part of the prerequisites installer

Answer (score 1):

May be you already fix the issues, But when we had the issue, we repair the DC.

Run the below powershell to repair it.

```
$instanceName ="SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService"
$serviceInstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.service.tostring()) -eq $instanceName -and ($_.server.name) -eq $env:computername}
$serviceInstance.delete()
```

Now run this one on each server you want to add into cluster.

```
Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
```

I highly recommend, start DC on the servers where you want.

Comment: Two years later - and it still works :)